# Lecture states that $A+B=A⊕B$

Tags: logic

I am reading a lecture on addition of binary and it's implementation as an expression (adders).

Let $C_i$ be the $ith$ boolean for the carry over, $A_i$ be the $ith$ position of a binary string input $A$, and similarly with $B_i$

We have the definition, from the simplification of minterms

$$
C_{i+1}=A_i B_i +C_i(A_i+B_i)$$

My problem is, it proceeded to the expression below
$$C_{i+1}=A_i B_i+C_i(A_i ⊕ B_i)$$

$$C_{i+1}=G_i+P_iC_i$$

The lecture implies that $A+B=A⊕B$ which is not the definition for exclusive-or
$$
A⊕B=A'B+AB'
$$

Comment: It does not imply that. $A_i+B_i=(A_i ⊕ B_i)+A_iB_i$, because exclusive OR differs from inclusive OR only in the case that both are $1$. But you have $A_iB_i$ added there already, so the extra term $C_iA_iB_i$ gets absorbed into it.

Comment: @Conifold how did you got that identity? From $A+B$ we have $
A+B+AB'+A'B=A+B+(A⊕B)
$ this is the closest I got

Comment: $A+AB'=A(1+B')=A$ and similarly $B+A'B=B$. The same absorption goes in $AB+CAB=AB$.

Comment: @Conifold I mean where did you got >$A_i+B_i=(A_i ⊕ B_i)+A_iB_i$? From your comment, all I got is $A_i+B_i=  (A_i ⊕ B_i)+A_i+B_i$

Comment: Look at your own expression on the left and apply what I wrote.

Comment: @Conifold after applying it, $A+B=A+AB'+B+A'B$ then $\Longrightarrow A+B = A + B + ( A_i ⊕ B_i)$.        So applying it back to the original expression, $C=AB+C(A+B)$ then $C=AB + C(A + B + ( A_i ⊕ B_i))$ I dont think that $CA$ and $CB$ can be absorbed by $AB$

Comment: Think it over, everything you need is already written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this post and [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255993/is-the-boolean-expression-wyz-wyz), I think it is important to realize that just because $X + \phi = X + \psi$ does not mean that $\phi = \psi$.

For example, we have that $X + 0 = X + X = X$, but clearly that does not mean that $X = 0$

Likewise, just because $X \phi = X \psi$ does not mean that $\phi = \psi$.

For example, we have that $X 1 = X X = X$, but clearly that does not mean that $X = 1$

So, your normal cancellation principles don't work for boolean algebra like they do for other algebras

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the lecture does not imply
$$
A+B=A⊕B
$$
Rather, it came from a three-steps simplification

$$
C_{i+1}=A_iB_i+C_i(A_i+B_i)
$$

$$
C_{i+1}=A_iB_i+C_i(A_i+A'_iB_i)
$$
$$
C_{i+1}=A_iB_i+C_i(A_iB_i+A_iB_i'+A_i'B_i)
$$
$$
C_{i+1}=A_iB_i+C_i(A_i⊕B_i)
$$